# Create two blank lines in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I am adding Markdown support to my [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) editor.

When writing Markdown content, how do I create two empty lines?

I have been trying, but I always get only one line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm using Markdown outside of a webapp so I would vote against.

Comment: @FactorMystic The question is about Markdown and not CMS. Markdown is not a web app, it is a formatting language.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

If your Markdown compiler supports HTML, you can add `<br/><br/>` in the Markdown source.

Comment: Well, yes but I was wondering if it was possible only in markdown syntax.

Comment: Markdown treats multiple blank lines as one blank line, you could `pre` tag to contain blank lines. As markdown inside `pre` block is not parsed. I would prefer not to do this, instead add as many `<br>`'s as needed.

Comment: It seems to me these tags sort of ruin my document if I want it to also look good as raw text.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work with output to PDF (via xelatex).

Comment: The answers languishing down below about using `\` at the end of a line and then making a new line seem better than this answer, since they use Markdown syntax only and keep the document human-readable. It seems not to work with all Markdown libraries, but it should still get more attention than it has so far.

Comment: `<br>` without trailing `/` should be sufficient

Answer (score 252):

I test on a lot of Markdown implementations. The non-breaking space ASCII character `&nbsp;` (followed by a blank line) would give a blank line. Repeating this pair would do the job. So far I haven't failed any.

For example:

Hello

world!

Comment: Markdown in bitbucket wiki doesn't support this unfortunately

Comment: This could be an issue in code-blocks, as "&nbsp;" will get rendered as "&nbsp;"

Comment: @david I tried this on the Daring Fireball 'Dingus' page, with <code> block, but with `backticks`, it does get rendered as &nbsp; where in HTML, it's `&amp;nbsp;`

Comment: I needed to add a space between two tables in a markdown file in TFS/VSTS and this did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This worked with markdown-deux for Django templates.  Thank you!

Comment: any suggestions for creating blank pages? (will be needing them for converting multiple `.md` files to a single pdf)

Comment: This worked in RMarkdown in RStudio, but so did the `br` tag, and as I think about what each tag is supposed to mean, I prefer `br`

Comment: Worked for me with R Markdown pdf output. Thanks. For blank pages, @pkaramol, if you are *inside* a code chunk, use `cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")`. Outside a code chunk, check out this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240541/how-to-add-newpage-in-rmarkdown-in-a-smart-way

Comment: In laravel I use 
`Str::of($comment->message)->replace("\n\n", "\n\xC2\xA0\n")->markdown(['html_input' => 'escape'])` since `&nbsp;` or `<br>` are escaped

Answer (score 82):

I only know the options below. It would be great to take a list of all of them and comment them differences

```sh
# RAW
## Creates 2 Lines that CAN be selected as text
## -------------------------------------------------
### The non-breaking space ASCII character
&nbsp;
&nbsp;

### HTML <(br)/> tag
<br />
<br />

## Creates 2 Lines that CANNOT be selected as text
## -------------------------------------------------
### HTML Entity &NewLine;
&NewLine;
&NewLine;

### Backticks with a space inside followed by two spaces
`(space)`(space)(space)
`(space)`(space)(space)
#### sample:
` `  
` `

# End
```

Comment: `&NewLine;` fit me, it genrate an empty `<p></p>` tag

Comment: I had success today with `&Newline;  ` , with two trailing spaces, in both HTML and Word, which is what I need right now :-)

Comment: Best answer is with the backticks! Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

In Markdown flavours that support equation output, the following should work on a line by itself, with empty lines before and after (repeat for more lines):

> $~$

It is basically an equation containing nothing but a single equation-white-space. The benefit is that in Markdown flavours that include both PDF and HTML output options (including Rmarkdown), it should be understood in the same way for both output types, whereas I'm not sure how PDF output would interpret <br> or &nbsp;

Comment: This solution worked for me in Reveal.js (better graded solutions did not work).

Answer (score 26):

Basically, if the library you are using is CommonMark-compliant, you can add multiple hard line breaks (`<br />`) easily. Here's a quotation from [CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org)'s latest specifications (0.28):

> A line break (not in a code span or HTML tag) that is preceded by two or more spaces and does not occur at the end of a block is parsed as a hard line break (rendered in HTML as a 
>  tag)

and then...

> For a more visible alternative, a backslash before the line ending may be used instead of two spaces

The specification is quite clear. However, the library I have been using [MarkDig](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig), doesn't quite work with the two spaces technique (must be a bug), but it works flawlessly with a backlash.

That said, this input...

```
Line one\
\
\
\
Line two
```

will produce four hard line breaks after "Line one". You can see it here (using backlash)...

https://babelmark.github.io/?text=Line+one%5C%0A%5C%0A%5C%0A%5C%0ALine+two%0A

Notice how all **CommonMark-compliant** implementations will get it right.

Comment: worked for me, thank you. The `\` generate a `<br>`

Comment: Another benefit in using the "\" character: My editor's delete-extra-whitespace settings does not trash the MD doc :)

Answer (score 14):

You can use `<br/><br/>` or `&nbsp;&nbsp;` or `\ \`.

Comment: If you create it in code add a new line char (`\n`) -> for example: `<br/><br/>\n`

Answer (score 13):

You can do it perfectly using this:

```
texttextexttexttext
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
texttexttexttexttext
```

Comment: A lot of suggestions work for some flavors of Markdown but not for Github Markdown. But this suggestion works even in Github Markdown.

Comment: This works with Bitbucket Markdown as well.

Answer (score 11):

In GitHub Wiki markdown I used hash marks (#) followed by two spaces to make the line break larger.  It doesn't actually give you multiple line breaks but it made one large line break and served me well for my needs.

Instead of:

```
text
(space)(space)
more text
```

I did:

```
text
(hash mark)(space)(space)
more text
```

Comment: underrated answer!

Answer (score 9):

Backtick quotes with a space inside and two spaces to follow. Repeat as needed for more lines:

```
text1 text1
`(space)`(space)(space)
`(space)`(space)(space)
text2 text2
```

It looks decent in Markdown source:

```
text1 text1
` `  
` `  
text2 text2
```

Comment: While this solution works the spaces would show up as actual characters in some markdown flavors such as that of Github

Answer (score 6):

```
&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp;<br>
```

new, three blank line. goodluck

Answer (score 5):

For an empty line in Markdown, escape a space (`\` ), and then add a new line.

Example:

"\

"

Remember: escape a space and escape a new line. That way is Markdown compliant and should compile properly in any compiler. You may have to select the example text to see how it is set up.

Comment: This does not work on Github markdown flavor. There, you have to add html tags <br><br>  or however many you need to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the sequence of a no-break space (`U+00a0`) followed by two spaces (`U+0020`×2) followed by a newline (`U+000a`) repeatedly to achieve this. Two or more times is required depending on your use case.

Using (not markdown interpreted *here*, but) actual white space characters (theoretically copy-and-paste-able):

```
Preceding
   
   
   
Following.
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything but this worked for me while using Pandoc markdown with TexLive as LaTex engine. 
In order to add blank lines, you can try adding a blank line but remove ""

```
## \newline
```

Just repeat the above, each will add a new blank line

Answer (score 3):

```
&nbsp;
```

This HTML entity which means **"non-breaking space"** will help you for each line break

Comment: That's what Aymen Jarouih's answer says and ngungo's answer both says and demonstates.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it works with other editors, but in VSCode a simple # followed immediately by a newline does the trick for my purposes and can be repeated infinitely. (Unlike the backtick quotes which have zero output there)

It is in fact an empty title line, though - so any document outline or auto-formatting might look funky.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a library like *markdown-it* or *PythonMarkdown* this can also be solved by replacing two line breaks (in Regex `/\n\n$/gm`) with a line break and an invisible character (`\n` ) before rendering. Note that the character after `\n` is an Alt+0160 or an [invisible character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800).

For example, using [markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it) (although it work for any other lib too) with the input:

```
1

2


3


4



5
```

Rendered with `md.render(string.data.replace(/\n\n$/gm, "\n "))` you will get:

[image]

Comment: The invisible character will mess things up involving lists and such by connecting one line to the next.

Comment: or replace \n\n to some string like 起2643勉 and then after render replace(/起2643勉/gm, "<br /><br />") but stlll issue with its allow one 1 new line 2 new line and 4 new line, 6 new line ;)

Answer (score -4):

Try adding multiple spaces (two spaces = one `<br>`):

```
mycode(space)(space)(space)(space)
```

Comment: The OP asked for a markdown technique that would produce two empty lines. Every markdown interpreter that I know of will convert 2+ spaces at the end of a line into a single break, not one break for every 2 spaces.