# How to add \newpage in Rmarkdown in a smart way?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I wonder if one could simply use LaTeX `\newpage` command in R markdown v2 in a different way than this:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat("\\newpage")
```
````

I produce pdf_output.
If any1 has any idea please do not hesitate to comment :) ! 
Thanks

I create pdf like this:

```
---
title: " "
author: " "
date: "2014"
output: 
   pdf_document:
      includes:
         in_header: naglowek.tex
      highlight: pygments
      toc: true
      toc_depth: 3
      number_sections: true
      keep_tex: true
---
```

Comment: And then what packages/functions do you use? Or do you just click buttons in RStudio?

Comment: What's the difference? My packages or functions has nothing to do with that I'd like to add newpage in some parts of code.

Comment: Its nice to see the complete workflow - there's various ways of going from markdown to PDF. Without that, we're guessing. Good guess @tonytonov

Comment: I don't think so it was a guess. It was easy question I think you overestimated it. Btw thanks for chat. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Simply `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` will work, e.g.

````
hello world
\newpage
```{r, echo=FALSE}
1+1
```
\pagebreak
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(1:10)
```
````

This solution assumes you are knitting PDF. For HTML, you can achieve a similar effect by adding a tag `<P style="page-break-before: always">`. Note that you likely won't see a page break in your browser (HTMLs don't have pages per se), but the printing layout will have it.

Comment: Does that have any effect when knitting to html? Does it cause any error?

Comment: Since it is a question about creating a newpage. How would you create a new page in html output?

Comment: @MarcinKosiński You can insert HTML tags directly: see edit for clarification.

Answer (score 39):

In the initialization chunk I define a function

```
pagebreak <- function() {
  if(knitr::is_latex_output())
    return("\\newpage")
  else
    return('<div style="page-break-before: always;" />')
}
```

In the markdown part where I want to insert a page break, I type

```
`r pagebreak()`
```

Answer (score 19):

You can make the pagebreak conditional on knitting to PDF.  This worked for me.

````
```{r, results='asis', eval=(opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to') == 'latex')}
cat('\\pagebreak')
```
````

Comment: This works great, creates a page break in PDF but does not output anything in HTML (where page breaks don't make sense). Seems wort it to update the main answer to add this possibility.

Comment: ```{r, results='asis', eval=(opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to') == 'latex')}
cat('\\pagebreak')
```   results in

`Error in eval(x, envir = envir) : object 'opts_knit' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> eval_lang -> eval -> eval
Execution halted`  `opts_knit$get` works fine in the console though. ?

Comment: add  `echo = FALSE` to the knitr opts to avoid to get the statement `cat('\\pagebreak')` in the output file.

Comment: @Akronix I used `cat('\\pagebreak')` in chunk and added `echo = FALSE` to the knitr opts, but still get "## \newpage" in my pdf, any idea why?

Comment: @BenjaminTelkamp You have to add also the results and eval arguments as stated in the answer. At least that works for me generating the pdf using `latex_engine: xelatex`.  

(Insert three backticks to the beginning and to the end of this code)  

     ```{r page break, results='asis', eval=(opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to') == 'latex'), echo = FALSE}
    cat('\\pagebreak')
    ```

Comment: I re-copy it here for better clarity:

Comment: `\`\`\`{r page break, results='asis', eval=(opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to') == 'latex'), echo = FALSE}
    cat('\\pagebreak')
    \`\`\`
`

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems with `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` and floating figures/tables. You need to use `\clearpage`, as answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2960/235920).