# Break R Markdown into pages with page number at the bottom

Tags: r, markdown, page-numbering

I have a markdown file which is very long so I want to break it into section with page numbers at the bottom so the reader can choose a page number.

I tried to use `page break` like this:

````
hello world
\newpage
```{r, echo=FALSE}
1+1
```
\pagebreak
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(1:10)
```
````

but there is still one markdown and not many pages. How can I produce a markdown using knite html with page numbers at the bottom for other pages?

Comment: As said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240541/how-to-add-newpage-in-rmarkdown-in-a-smart-way: For HTML, you can achieve a similar effect by adding a tag <P style="page-break-before: always">. Note that you likely won't see a page break in your browser (HTMLs don't have pages per se), but the printing layout will have it.

Comment: @warmoverflow but I want to present the html file. is it possible to add page numbers like page 1, 2, 3, 4 and each page is after the `\pagebreak` ?

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to output a slide deck instead of raw html. Then the page numbers are handled for you...