# Latex and Pandoc Resume

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I am using markdown and pandox latex template to generate a CV. I want to be able to add spacing between items.

Markdown

```
# Education
2019
University of Minesota
```

The PDF output shows:

Education

2019 University of Minesota.

Im trying to see how can I add arbitrary horizontal space between the dates and the descriptions still using a combination of markdown and Pandoc tex files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help:

```
---
title: "CV"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{enumitem}
---

# Education

## You can use a hspace

2019 \hspace*{1cm} University of Minesota


## with the enumitem package

\begin{itemize}[labelindent=1em,labelsep=1cm,leftmargin=*]
  \item[2010] Kindergarden
  \item[2019] University of Minesota
\end{itemize}

## Or with html

2019 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; University of Minesota
```

And you can have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721373/how-do-i-ensure-that-whitespace-is-preserved-in-markdown)

Comment: I didn't know you can use style elements in markdown